# Enum in Java doesn't allow to implement a method in its implementing interface

Tags: java, enums

The following simple code snippet uses the interface `Named` containing two methods namely `name()` and `order()` which is being implemented by `enum` named `Days`. The `enum Days` doesn't allow to implement the `name()` method of its implementing interface. Doing so, causes a compile-time error and although the `name()` method is not implemented by the `enum`, it doesn't issue any error.

```
package enumpkg;

interface Named
{
    public String name();
    public int order();
}

enum Days implements Named
{
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday;

    public int order()
    {
        return ordinal()+1;
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Monday    = "+Days.Monday.order());
        System.out.println("Tuesday   = "+Days.Tuesday.order());
        System.out.println("Wednesday = "+Days.Wednesday.order());
        System.out.println("Thursday  = "+Days.Thursday.order());
        System.out.println("Friday    = "+Days.Friday.order());
        System.out.println("Saturday  = "+Days.Saturday.order());
        System.out.println("Sunday    = "+Days.Sunday.order());
    }
}
```

---

The code works without implementing the `name()` method in `enum`. How?

---

The output is quite obvious as shown below.

```
Monday    = 1
Tuesday   = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday  = 4
Friday    = 5
Saturday  = 6
Sunday    = 7
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Did you read it?

Comment: I agree with SLaks - it is very important to actually read compilation error messages, and try and understand what they are telling you.

Comment: It indicates that the overridden method `name()` is `final` and can not be overridden.

Comment: I start to think the gcc devs were on to something when they made their error messages unreadable - wasted effort to try to create good, meaningful error messages :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base `Enum` class already has a [`name()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29).
Since this method is `final`, you can't override it (as the error message clearly states).

Answer (score 3):

From the Java API, name() is defined as:

`public final String name()`

Thus name() exists for all enums, and is not overridable.

See also: [Java API for enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29)